# How do I set max-age for the XSRF-Token cookie generated by spring boot

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, csrf

I am enabling csrf protection and setting the XSRF-TOKEN cookie using spring boot

In the browser I see the cookie is set as expected, but with no experation. I have these questions

1. Is there a way i can set the max age on this cookie or make it expire when the session expires?
2. Should I be storing the XSRF Token in a session instead of cookie for a better security?
3. What is the best way to do CSRF protection with AngularJS as front end and springboot as backened?

here is my springboot code

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
    .and().csrf()
.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way i can set the max age on this cookie or make it expire when the session expires?

There should be no need to change the max age of the cookie, because by default `CookieCsrfTokenRepository` creates it so that it will not be stored persistently. It will usually be deleted when the browser is closed:

```
cookie.setMaxAge(-1);
```

But if you REALLY want to change it, you would have to write your own implementation of `CsrfTokenRepository`, because although it would be nice to just override the `saveToken(...)` method of `CookieCsrfTokenRepository`, you can't because it is a `final` class. Instead, you could use composition and have your implementation delegate to a `CookieCsrfTokenRepository` object for every method call except `saveToken(...)`, which is where you would write your custom cookie logic. Then add it in your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.
    ...
    .and().csrf()
    .csrfTokenRepository(new MyCustomCookieCsrfTokenRepository());
}
```

Again, think twice about whether this is necessary.

> Should I be storing the XSRF Token in a session instead of cookie for a better security?

Well, if someone can steal your cookies, they could theoretically steal your session as well. If you can maintain state in the server for the value of the cookie, then go ahead. But if not, stick with the cookie. Spring Security takes care of the details.

> What is the best way to do CSRF protection with AngularJS as front end and springboot as backened?

One approach is sending the CRSF token as a cookie, and having your ANgularJS application send the token back in the "X-XSRF-TOKEN" header, or as a request parameter with the name "_csrf".

If you want to store the CSRF value in the session, you would need to have a way of making your AngularJS app aware of it. Traditionally, in a non single-page setting, you would write it in a form as a hidden parameter. But since this is not your case, you might want to stick with using a cookie.